# CSP tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There are some 40 questions tagged with [csp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csp) (a tag without any tag info or usage guidance).

It is used, amongst other things, for

- Content Security Policy (there is already a tag
  content-security-policy)
- Constraint Satisfaction Problem
- Communicating Sequential Processes
- Cryptographic Service Provider
- Cloud Solution Provider

In some cases it is simply used, without any indication what for. I suggest to remove the tag.

Comment: Completely *Sans* Purpose?

Comment: For 35 questions, if you have the power to edit them, simply gently remove the tags and clean up the questions, maybe over a period of 5 days, 7 per day, not to overstress those who worry about the questions hitting the top of the front page again because of the edits.  The tag is meaningless because it has no definition and has been used for many purposes — it should undoubtedly go (IMNSHO, of course).

Comment: Content Scope Problem ; Classification Scope Problem ; Creativity Smackdown Policy ; Crepuscular Sesquipedalian Potentiate ; Creative Scottish Plaid ; Covert Scottish Plasmid

Comment: I would create tag `communicating-sequential-processes` but it is over 25 characters limit. Any suggestions for naming?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I will do that. Once I am done, can I delete the tag myself or do I need to alert a moderator ?

Comment: Once there are no questions left with the tag, it is removed automatically after about 24 hours.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thank you @JonathanLeffler for your help.

Comment: Well done.  Thanks for taking on the job.

Comment: Looks like it was re-created almost 1 year after @JonathanLeffler's efforts. There's 42 posts now.

Comment: @BhargavRao: I'd forgotten about this skirmish in the 'tagging wars'.  Looks like most need the [tag:csp] tag removed and some need [tag:content-security-policy] tag added.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, and some of them are completely off topic. You free for some burnination? I can start from the end and travel upwards (sorted newest).

Comment: @BhargavRao: fine — meet somewhere in the middle.  One dozen down from my end.

Comment: We seem to have reached the end.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, we've cleared this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give this question an answer so it can be accepted/closed:

- In late December 2016, the [csp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csp) tag was cleaned up and removed — if I read the comment trail correctly, mostly by [Eike Pierstorff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/761212/eike-pierstorff).  A search on my edit history shows 3 edits which mentioned that the CSP tag was being removed (so I definitely didn't do very much).
- In mid June 2018, it was noted that the [csp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csp) tag had been reincarnated, and it had a Wiki entry this time, which said "Do not use the tag because it is ambiguous" and "Use [content-security-policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-security-policy) for questions about Content Security Policy".  The questions with the tag were swiftly edited and the tag expunged by Yours Truly (aka [Jonathan Leffler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)) and [Bhargav Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao) — elapsed time barely over 15 minutes.  About a day later, the tag has vanished again (automatically; the system removes entries for tags with no questions using the tag on a daily sweep), awaiting its next reincarnation.

So, until the next time, this is finished — hence the 'status completed' tag.